# Emit each item from Flowable Room ORM

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I have a list of items in the Room ORM which I would like to display in a Recycler view. The data is being added from the network to the db. The problem is I am getting every time the whole list emited from the Flowable and not each item. I have tried with .distinctUntilChanged with no difference.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM items")
Flowable<List<Item>> getItems();
```

I have tried also to return only a single item which loads only the first one that is the db.

Comment: You can use flatMap() to get Flowable<Item> from Flowable<List<Item>>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to get stream of items.

```
itemDao.getItems().flatMap(list -> {
      Item[] items = new Item[list.size()];
      list.toArray(items);
      return Flowable.fromArray(items);
    }).subscribe(item -> {
      // Now you can do with each item.

    });
```

If you only need the first item:

```
itemDao.getItems().flatMap(list -> {
          Item[] items = new Item[list.size()];
          list.toArray(items);
          return Flowable.fromArray(items);
        })
         .firstElement()
         .subscribe(first -> {
          // Now you can do with the first one.

        });
```

Comment: As he mentioned in the question, you can say `Flowable<Item> getItems()` to get only the first item.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, `Flowable<List<Item>>` means you'll get a single callback when the list changes: this is how Room works. Generally, you'd pass that list into [`DiffUtil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html), which then generates the set of changes needed to update your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: For more information on `DiffUtil`, I'd start with [this blog post](https://medium.com/@jonfhancock/get-threading-right-with-diffutil-423378e126d2), even though it isn't Rx based.

Comment: Yes diff util should work. I went with a distinct function based on the id of the items which seems to work.

Comment: Strongly consider moving properties like uniqueness into your database, rather than doing it as post processing - Room does support auto-generating IDs and unique columns

Comment: I have a unique id in the database. The problem is that it brings back the whole table   so I need to filter this after retrieving from the db.

Comment: DiffUtil requires the whole list - it computes the additions, removals, and changes for you by comparing the old list to the new. If you're always filtering in the same way, that should be on the database side or part of your Dao

Answer (score 4):

You can use `flatMap` and `Flowable.fromIterable()` to map to `Flowable` which will emit all items one by one

```
getItems()
    .flatMap(Flowable::fromIterable)
    .subscribe(item -> {

    });
```

That's it. Short and clean code, without casting `toArray`