# How can I selectively observe Android Room database INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE events?

Tags: android, android-room, rx-android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have DAO designed this way.

```java
@Dao
interface FooDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM foo")
    LiveData<List<Foo>> stream();
}
```

The above lets me receive `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` events all at once, which I have no way of knowing whether the data is recently inserted, deleted, or being updated.

#### Goal

My goal is to be able to update the database rapidly and have RecyclerView reflect the changes without stuttering or completely freezing.

#### Current situation

I have a background service that's updating the database and using the above method, I'm using the [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) class to calculate the difference and update the list accordingly on the front end.

#### Issue

Because updates are coming in so fast, the RecyclerView gets frozen up. I added background processing (DiffUtil calculation) using RxJava (since I have it in there anyway), which only reduced the stutter significantly though not completely.

#### Ideal goal

I need to figure out a way to update the list individually or if at all possible, skip receiving only `UPDATE` events from Room leaving out `INSERT` and `DELETE` events since these are done manually so should not be able to freeze the UI.

That way, I can use EventBus to notify the adapter that a row has changed from the background service without triggering `UPDATE` events from Room, which would have otherwise caused the adapter to perform the DiffUtil calculation, therefore slowing the UI down.

This means isolating database events for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, and `UPDATE` or selectively observing specific events only.

Is there such a way with Room and if so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `ListAdapter` from RecyclerView extensions?

Comment: I was going to write an answer but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380018/2235972) basically covers it.

Comment: @sonnet Getting individual row/items is just as getting all of them at once. I want to be able to tell whether the emission is an INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE. Or alternatively skip UPDATE emission, that way, I can still add and remove from the list but not get UPDATE events because i'd be manually sending those from the background thread. But it's a solution worth looking at nonetheless.

Comment: The cleanest approach would be to observe the flowable/livedata returned from `getItems()` func from your dao. Whenever insert/delete/update changes your db, `getItems()` will emit items again and you'll pass this to the listadapter `adapter.submitList(items)`. ListAdapter will do all the diffing on a background thread and will remove/insert/update items with animation and you won't have to do anything. If you have a very large list, consider using the paging library, because the approach I mentioned will return you the entire list and all of it will be kept in memory of your viewmodel.